# What conditions does a functor $F: C\longrightarrow D$ need to satisfy such that its image is a subcategory of $D$?

Tags: category-theory, functors

Is injectivity-on-objects sufficient?
Is such a factorization always the epi-mono factorization or are there other  subtle differences one needs to be aware of?

Comment: Do you mean epi-mono factorization for the *functors*, i.e. for the category of (small) categories?

Comment: Yes! But I'm also general factorization systems for F: C -> D into G: C ->Im(F) and H: Im(F) -> D. Are there such? Is epi-mono the only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the *image* of a functor $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ is meant in the concrete way:
 $\mathrm{im}\, F$ is the collection of objects $F(x)$ for $x\in Ob\,\mathcal C$ and of morphisms $F(f)$ for $f\in Mor\,\mathcal C$.

Now, as the title suggests, this collection might fail to be a subcategory, and this happens only if there are morphisms $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y'\to Z$ in $\mathcal C$ with $Y\ne Y'$, such that
$$F(Y)=F(Y')\ \ \text{ and }\ \ F(g)\circ F(f)\notin\mathrm{im}\,F\,.$$

In light of this, injectivity on objects is indeed a sufficient condition.

However, regarding the factorization question, the picture is not that clear as for plain algebraic structures.
Exactly because of the above behavior, $\mathrm{im}\,F\,\subseteq\mathcal D$ is not necessarily a subcategory, hence it is *not necessarily a category* in itself, i.e. not an object of $\mathcal Cat$, so in general, the concrete image cannot be the image with respect to any factorization system on $\mathcal Cat$.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer - I was wondering if this is the only way for this condition to fail to be a subcategory. Is there a book/resource which talks about htis and similar issues regarding images of morphisms in various categories? And this also now got me wondering about a possible generalization: does any monomorphism F: C -> D admit a factorization into two monomorphisms: C -> Im(F) -> D?

Comment: Well, then $C\cong im(F)$..

Comment: Well, each object in the image will have  its identity there as well. Only closure under composition may fail..

Comment: Right, $C \cong im(F)$. It seems to me there is a similar notion: full image of a functor: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+image

Comment: In other words, it seems that _every_ functor $F: C \rightarrow D$ has a decomposition $C \cong \overline{im}(F) \rightarrow D$

Comment: Yes, there are various factorizations, but none of them can capture exactly the literal image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94687/discussion-between-bruno-gavranovic-and-berci).